When Hashem wishes to punish someone He takes away their bitachon
BH
Hi, I read in Shaar Bitachon page 4 in the White version with Chassidic notes, in the commentary, that the Baal Shem Tov said that a person must pray that his trust be strengthened, because when Hashem wants to punish someone, He begins by taking away his trust in Him.
What did the Baal Shem Tov mean when he said this? Is there another source in Talmud that can explain this? Also are there other things you can do to strengthen trust and remove this specific punishment that removes trust in Hashem?

There is a Ramban that says that before people relied on medicine, they didn't need it and could go to a prophet who would help them do teshuva, as sin was the only way they could get sick. After they started having bitachon for medicine and doctors, Hashem made it so they need to take medicine, because He made them start getting sick due to the "happenings of the world" instead of (just) sin. See Berachot 60a for his source. This feels nogeah

Can you please provide the name of the Sefer. Sounds very interesting

@Yoreinu it would also be useful for the sake of seeing exactly what is said - why does Hashem "want" to punish this person? What's the context

David, in the particular edition (Fellah edition from Kehot) of Sha’ar HaBitachon, it should list the specific source and page for  quote from the Ba’al Shem Tov. Please provide it so that we can hopefully answer your question.

It says in the book one of the Benifits of trust is the tranquility of the soul which is free of worry as a result of his reliance of G-d* [then the comment says on this ]

Trust in G-d has its own inherent benefit

The Ba’al Shem tov teaches a person must pray for his trust to be strengthened because when G-d desires to punish, he begins by removing that persons trust in him(Keter Shem Tov 382)
